# MyBatis Encoding special character

Tags: java, sql, db2, mybatis

I have to do a select with myBatis to DB2 database. In the database there is a value that contains an arrow character like this  "" (arrow character, ASCII table Decimal 26).
When I run the query it return this error:

> javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException:
>   com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Illegal character
>   ((CTRL-CHAR, code 26))  at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,333]    at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)

and I can't to get the value.

How can I fix this problem?
I checked that in DB2 there is a UTF-8 encoding. 
DB2 version 9.4 z/OS

Comment: Edit your question to add missing information: What is your Db2 driver version+fixpack?  What is your Db2-server operating-system?

Comment: Still missing your client-side Db2 driver version. Have you checked the client side Db2 diagnostics file to see if there is an exception reported by the Db2 client?

Comment: Maybe you dont understand the question.. the select query work fine but when I try to launch from my application it returns the error that there is an invalid character. On the db2 workstation the query work fine and return the values

Comment: That information (re correct result set from Db2) was missing from the question. Sometimes errors like this are version-specific in Db2 client, but if the Db2-client gets correct result set then the issue is not with the Db2-client.  Maybe examine your XML (if using that) or how you've configured MyBatis.